# MSI Installer not working when run from task scheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, windows-task-scheduler

I have a .msi installer that installs a component of an application that my company develops. I am trying to automate the installation process.

I have found that the msi installs fine when I run it from the GUI, when I run the silent install commands from PowerShell, schedule the task to run  as a user who is logged in but fails when I try to schedule it to run as a user that never logged in. In this situation I get the following error message:

```
*MSI (s) (B8:C8) [16:58:06:301]: Closing MSIHANDLE (498) of type 790542 for thread 3784
MSI (s) (B8:C8) [16:58:06:316]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (B8:C8) [16:58:06:316]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (B8:BC) [16:58:06:316]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (B8:BC) [16:58:06:316]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
=== Logging stopped: 7/5/2020  16:58:06 ===
MSI (s) (B8:BC) [16:58:06:316]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:BC) [16:58:06:316]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:BC) [16:58:06:316]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (B8:BC) [16:58:06:316]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:BC) [16:58:06:316]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:BC) [16:58:06:316]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (B8:BC) [16:58:06:316]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (B8:78) [16:58:06:316]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (c) (A4:E8) [16:58:06:332]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (A4:E8) [16:58:06:332]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 7/5/2020  16:58:06 ===*
```

I need fix this issue because the application will be installed silently on a new server that no one has logged into.

I have scheduled the task to run whether the user is logged in or not and run with the highest privileges. Anyone have any ideas what maybe causing this and how I can get around it?

Comment: it appears that the author wrote the code to REQUIRE that the user have logged in at least once. there are two solutions that come to mind ... [1] fix the installer. [2] log that user account into the target system as the 1st part of your install.

Comment: The question is if you really need to run as a specific user or if you can install for all users on the box? (per-machine installation).

Answer (score 1):

***Logging***: That log is too short to determine what is going on. [Have a look at this answer on logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890).

---

***Impersonation***: MSI GUI is run in user context. The actual installation is run as LocalSystem (system context). Skipping the user interface runs everything in system context. Running as a user without generated profile will not allow proper folder resolution and a runtime error is likely. Some installers are made to be per-user only (not that many). Most can be installed for all users.

---

***Per-Machine***: MSI files should install OK without any logged in user in most cases if you install "per-machine" - that means that the software is installed for all users on the machine.

Can you show us the exact command line you use to install the software? ([sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30762288/129130))

***Custom Actions***: Some custom actions are badly designed and cause failure in scenarios that involve user profile activity - that could be the cause of this problem as well. Try another MSI for testing?

---

***Important note***: The below may not be relevant for your case, but you should know about these technical details for your overall scenario (silent running of MSI installers):

[***UILevel***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uilevel): You should be aware that [UILevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uilevel) affects installation and uninstallation (different levels of silent running for MSI files - 4 in total). Have a quick read here please: [Uninstall from Control Panel is different from Remove from .msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677483/uninstall-from-control-panel-is-different-from-remove-from-msi/29679464#29679464)

---

***Further Links***:

- [InstrallShield Basic MSI uninstall does not display a dialog with Finish button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931864/instrallshield-basic-msi-uninstall-does-not-display-a-dialog-with-finish-button/49932152#49932152)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/11670/the-corporate-benefits-of-using-msi-files

Comment: Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList '/lvx* "<log-file-path>" /i "<msi-location>" /qr DATA_FILE_DIR="C:\ProgramData\Databases" LOG_FILE_DIR="C:\ProgramData\Databases"  SSIS_SERVER="Local" SSAS_SERVER="Local" SSRS_SERVER="Local" UPGRADE="0" ACCEPTEULA=YES' -RedirectStandardOutput '<output-location>' -RedirectStandardError '<error-log>' -PassThru -Wait -NoNewWindow

Comment: Installer is designed to install custom databases into SQL server. I have removed usernames and passwords that are also passed into the installer

Comment: There are several other MSI files that install fine