# WiX Bootstrapper. Unable to connect msi package

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer, installation

In my bootstrapper i need to call third-party msi package. But i got an error `error LGHT0364: The MSI ... set the ALLUSERS Property to ... which is not supported. Remove the Property with Id='ALLUSERS' and use Package/@InstallScope attribute instead.`

Any ideas how to fix it? Or any ideas how to call this third-party msi differently.

I connect the packages in the chain like this:

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web" />
  <RollbackBoundary />
  <MsiPackage Id="CSP" SourceFile="$(env.WIX_CSP_MSI)" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Compressed="no"></MsiPackage>
  <MsiPackage Id="Dict" SourceFile="$(env.WIX_DICT_MSI)" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Compressed="no" Vital="yes">
  </MsiPackage>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(env.WIX_MSI_PATH)" >
    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" 
                 Value="[InstallFolder]" />
  </MsiPackage>
</Chain>
```

Comment: Probably this: "Instead of setting ALLUSERS explicitly, try setting the InstallScope of the Package element to perMachine. According to the documentation, this fact:": https://stackoverflow.com/a/17879980/4181058

Comment: I saw that. But it should be done for current msi package. But i can't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[ALLUSERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/allusers)***: It might be that your different MSI files have different values for [ALLUSERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/allusers) hard-coded in the [**`Property Table`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/property-table)? I am not sure what rules WiX enforces here, but it is natural to want to install all MSI setups in the same context. [ALLUSERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/allusers) determines whether the setup is installed per-user or per-machine.

> ***Hard Coded***: Maybe check the MSI files in question using **Orca** or [**an equivalent MSI viewer tool**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546) and see what the
>   value for [ALLUSERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/allusers) is in the Property table?

Comment: That could be a good idea. But i decide to wrap that msi with .exe file and use ExePackage. And it works fine.

Comment: OK, maybe check what context the different MSI files then install in. Log in as a different user and see if the application you installed is available for them to use as well. If not the application will only be available for the user who installed the setup (typically no launch shortcuts found for other users).