# Wix Toolset v3 Uninstaller Accessing C:\Windows\Temp?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, wix3

I have an .NET application that I am delivering via Wix v3 with a Xeam Visual Installer Bootstrapper. I can successfully install and uninstall my application with no issue when launching the setup.exe directly. However, if I attempt to remove the application via the add/remove feature in the control panel, I’m running into an issue where it does not complete.  I've discovered that, during installation, Wix(Burn?) places a folder in "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" that contains a copy of the setup.exe to provide the add/remove page a list of application that can be removed and known path to that application’s setup.exe in case an end user deletes the original after a successful installation. I checked the Event Viewer and saw this error:

**“[UserName] ran C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{d19c6399-6fa3-4ec1-9ff5-8e591dd0b581}\Demuxer Setup.exe, which tried to access the file C:\Windows\Temp{2F2F6C34-5EA3-4D38-883C-038F2DDBADDB}.ba\mbahost.dll, violating the rule "Running files from common user folders", and was blocked. For information about how to respond to this event, see KB85494.”**

After some research, I learned that this was a McAfee restriction that **“Blocks any executable from running or starting from any folder with “temp” in the folder name”**.

My question is **What is attempting to access this mbahost.dll in the C:\Windows\Temp folder and do I have any option to change that location so that it isn't located in a folder named "temp" which violates an McAfee policy that I can't disable?**  I've checked my installer logs and see no reference to this location so I'm a bit puzzled.  Thank you.

Product.wxs

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<?define CompanyName="Company Here" ?>
<?define ProductName="Demuxer" ?>
<Product Id="*"
         Name="$(var.ProductName)"
         Language="1033"
         Version="1.0.0.0"
         Manufacturer="$(var.CompanyName)"
         UpgradeCode="61D0E0AF-3F97-43D3-9880-645A1A81D8C4">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200"
             Compressed="yes"
             InstallScope="perMachine"/>

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature"
             Title="Demuxer.Installer.Package"
             Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="Components.Dependencies" />
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="Components.Demuxer.Viewer" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR"
               Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="Folder.CompanyName"
                       Name="$(var.CompanyName)">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER"
                           Name="$(var.ProductName)">
                    <Directory Id="Folder.LibVlc"
                               Name="libvlc"/>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

Bundle.wxs

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
<?define CompanyName="Company Here" ?>
<?define ProductName="Demuxer" ?>
<?define ProductVersion="1.0.0" ?>
<Bundle Name="$(var.ProductName)"
        Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
        Manufacturer="$(var.CompanyName)"
        UpgradeCode="BFD3AF26-02E1-4167-8370-DB4A2F4C15E6">

    <!-- Payload, that has to be added to run the bootstrapper application -->
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
        <PayloadGroupRef Id="VisualInstallerRuntimeFiles"/>
        <bal:WixManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost LicenseFile="Resources\License.rtf"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl"
                 Value="" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId"
                 Value="" />

    <Variable Name="LICENSESTRING"
              bal:Overridable="no"
              Value=""/>
    <Variable Name="SQLCONNECTIONSTRING"
              bal:Overridable="no"
              Value=""/>
    <Variable Name="INSTALLDIR"
              bal:Overridable="no"
              Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]$(var.CompanyName)\$(var.ProductName)"/>

    <Chain>
        <MsiPackage Vital ="yes"
                    Id="Msi.Demuxer.Installer.Package"
                    SourceFile="$(var.Demuxer.Installer.Package.TargetPath)"/>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Comment: Please add your Wix files to your post. The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878460/setting-the-allusers-option-on-wix-installer-does-not-work and https://security.stackexchange.com/a/254489